# Content is Scrollable or not in WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

How to know Content is Scrollable or not in WebView in Android. I have some conditions based on that, Is there any method? Thanks in Advance. I have seen onScrollChanged() and onOverScrolled() method it's called when we touch on the screen, but I need without it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution

```
override 
fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
super.onPageFinished(view, url)
if (computeVerticalScrollRange()<=computeVerticalScrollExtent()) {
         // logic here.... 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following View methods:

```
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction)
public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction)
```

direction – Negative to check scrolling up/left, positive to check scrolling down/right.

Comment: Any Full Example, How is this Work?